# Add a gridLayout(2,2) in CENTER

Tags: java, layout, grid

I want to create a gridLayout with 4 buttons at the center of my Layout, and a button to PAGE_END,PAGE_START,LINE_END,LINE_START. My code does show the last buttons I told you, but not the grid button ones.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Hello World!");
    frame.setSize(400,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2,2);
    p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JButton bg1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    p.add(bg1, c);
    JButton bg2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    p.add(bg2, c);
    JButton bg3 = new JButton("Button 3");
    p.add(bg3, c);
    JButton bg4 = new JButton("Button 4");
    p.add(bg4, c);

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());        

    JButton b1 = new JButton("TOP");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("LEFT");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("RIGHT");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("BOTTOM");       

    frame.add(b1,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.add(b2,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    frame.add(b3,BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    frame.add(b4,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the panel `p`, but you haven't added it to your frame.

Add this line in your code:

```
frame.add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Also, you must use this line, if you want the buttons in a grid:

```
p.setLayout(grid);
```

instead of `p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());`

Comment: First of all thanks for the help. I did add this line, but the Grid buttons/panel still not show. I also added `p.setVisible(true);` but still not working.

Comment: @iraklis.s Where have you added this line?

Comment: `JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 frame.add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
 p.setVisible(true);`

Comment: @iraklis.s I added this line **exactly before** you add other components (b1, b2...). It works fine.

Comment: Oh yeah it did!! Thanks!! So now, how do I make those buttons be 2 on Top and 2 on Bottom? Because right now they are in line. I want 2 lines of 2 buttons.

Comment: @iraklis.s Use GridLayout.